# How can I only capture string within url() with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'll try and make this concise.

I want to only capture the string within the parenthesis of:
`background-image:url()`

I've tried for hours and the best I could come up with was `(?<!\@\*)(?<=url\().*(?=\))`.
([Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/3PfViD/6))

This is almost perfect except when there is a run on line like this or any minified CSS code:
`background-image:url(/images/products/test@2x.png);height:0;background-image:url("/images/products/test@2x.png")`

It captures everything from the first open parentheses to the last closed parenthesis including the irrelevant styles in between.

I only want to capture the string between the `url()`'s.

Comment: You're gonna love this solution. Regex has non-greedy operators, so instead of `.*`, use `.*?`

Comment: [Here's a helpful link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: By default, all operators like `*` and `+` are greedy, which means they'll match anything and everything they possibly can. Using `*?` or `+?` means they'll match stuff till the bare minimum limit. So the minute they find that the match can be finished, they'll stop. Greedy operators would match everything until the final possible character, which in your case was until the second parentheses of the same line.

Comment: You have helped me so much. Such a simple solution, thank you so much. I wish I asked sooner, I was getting so frustrated and i didn't know how to phrase the issue in google.

Comment: I completely understand, because this was one of the very first issues I faced :)

Comment: Beware though, you could have a stoopid case like `background-image: url("/stoopid/file(name).jpg")`. non-greedy would get fooled here.

Comment: @Kaiido Do you have any ideas to cover those instances. It's not vital for the work I'm doing but I like learning regex info if you have the energy to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the regex which will work for you:

```
(?<!\@\*)(?<=url\().*?(?=\))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using positive and negative lookbehind: `/(?<=background-image:\s*url\().*(?=\))/ig` will return everything inside the `background-image: url()` call, with `\s*` to catch spaces.

Answer (score 1):

use regex

`(?<=background-image:url\()(.+?)(?=\))`

can found all `xxx` in `background-image:url(xxx)`, while not include `background-image:url()`

you can check result in: https://regexr.com , like this:

[image]

### Note:

1. about `look around` = `look ahead` and `look behind`, here is my summary:

[image]

2. more detail can refer (Chinese) tutorial: [环视断言 · 应用广泛的超强搜索：正则表达式](https://book.crifan.com/books/super_search_regex/website/regex_syntax/look_around/)